# the camera feed display a only green when I lunched a URL in a flutter APP

Tags: flutter

I'm currently having this problem. when I use my camera on the web page launched by a APP I created. the returning camera feed only show a green display. I try the same process on my computer and the feed is normal. I not sure what is coursing this problem, can anyone help?

I tried google for the solution, I also saw some people had the same problem as me, but no solution is found. I even tried asking GPT but to no avail.